# why does error PLS-00122 code occur for my trigger code in ORACLE SQL 11G

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

im a newbie in ORACLE 11G syntax especially triggers, may i know why does the following error occur?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER constraint_trig 
      AFTER INSERT ON booking_room FOR EACH ROW 
      BEGIN  
    IF (exists(SELECT booking_room.guest_NRIC, booking.check_in, booking.check_out, COUNT(*)  
          FROM booking_room, guest 
          WHERE guest.NRIC=booking_room.guest_NRIC 
          GROUP BY booking_room.guest_NRIC, booking_room. check_in, booking_room.check_out HAVING COUNT(*)>5))
    THEN raise_application_error (-20000, 'cannot have more than '); 
    END IF;   
    END; 
    /

>
```

output error:

LINE/COL ERROR

---

2/7      PLS-00122: CURSOR as separator is allowed only with specific
built-in functions

Comment: Did you mean to say "IF ( exits ( select ..."? Or should it be "IF ( exists ( select ..."?

Comment: i actually meant if exists

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're trying to solve or question you're asking. Simply repeating the information already available in the tags you've used provides no meaningful information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to future site users who are scanning a list of search results trying to find a problem solution. Tag repetition has no value for that purpose.